# OpenSSL for making iOS certs on a windows machine - do I need a server?

Tags: windows, cordova, openssl

I'm running Windows 7 Pro, not a server, and am wondering if I need a server to run openssl for the purpose of setting up my iOS certs for PhoneGap?

I've installed opensll, and am following instructions for making the cert here:
http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows#more-2582

But when I enter 
    openssl genrsa -des3 -out ios.key 2048 
it tells me 'opensll is an invalid command', displays a list of standard commands, and I cannot find the file ios.key on my machine.

I'm running the command window by shift-right-clicking on the bin folder in OpenSSL-Win64

Am I on the right track?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You probably need to put the OpenSSL binaries on path. See, for example, [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - for anyone else looking, I found a great guide to the whole process here:

http://support.brightcove.com/en/app-cloud/docs/step-step-guide-publishing-apple-app-store-using-windows

I was running the Shining Light installation of openssl from my own command window instead of running openssl.exe, which is why I was getting the 'opensll is an invalid command' error. But even so, errors about missing equal signs from the openssl.cnf (which I hadn't touched) kept displaying when running openssl.exe. I instead used a different openssl installation, found in the above link, which worked fine.

Comment: this is essentially a link only answer. While its great that you took the time to share the fix, you should explicitly state what fixed your particular problem so others can benefit.